# Update OpenGL to 2.0

Tags: opengl

I want to play a number of games that I have installed on my Ubuntu Install, however in order to do that my OpenGL is outdated, usually requiring version 2.0 as a minimal. I want to install 2.0, but using oibafs drivers, which update it to 3.0, my computer becomes an unstable mess. Is there any way to update it to 2.0 and not 3.0.

Computer Specs: HP Compaq nx7400, intel centrino duo processor. 100 GB hard disk, with ubuntu and windows taking 50gb each (That is unimportant, but just in case). 2gb RAM installed.

Also slightly important, current OpenGL version is 1.4.0.

Output of `glxinfo|grep version`

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
```

Output of `lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f4400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=8]
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f4480000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f4500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f4580000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=08, subordinate=08, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff
    Memory behind bridge: 44000000-441fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000044200000-00000000443fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=10, subordinate=10, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff
    Memory behind bridge: f4000000-f40fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000044400000-00000000445fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=20, subordinate=20, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: f0000000-f3ffffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000044600000-00000000447fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    I/O ports at 4020 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 4040 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at f4584000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=06, sec-latency=32
    I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00007fff
    Memory behind bridge: f4100000-f43fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000040000000-0000000043ffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01) (prog-if 80 [Master])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374
    I/O ports at 40a0 [size=16]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

02:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 18
    Memory at f4100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=06, sec-latency=176
    Memory window 0: 40000000-43ffffff (prefetchable)
    Memory window 1: 48000000-4bffffff
    I/O window 0: 00007000-000070ff
    I/O window 1: 00007400-000074ff
    16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus

02:06.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 30a2
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 19
    Memory at f4101000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Memory at f4104000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci

02:0e.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company NX7300 laptop
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 16
    Memory at f4108000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: b44

10:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and openGL are you currently using?

Comment: 1.4.0 unfortunately.

Comment: Which games do you want - nearly every game works on various machines with Opengl 1.4 - also what is the output of `glxinfo | grep version` and the bits about graphics in `lspci -v`?

Comment: Games like Starbound (min. 2.0), Portal (min 2.0) and minecraft (1.4.0 supported, but they claim they are planning to drop it).